A probably Fantasy middle-length fiction about a probable vampire during the Blitz
I read this novella (or perhaps a very long novelette) about 20 years ago in a collection that was probably somewhat older.
During the Blitz, the volunteers who dug the rubble caused by the bombs to find survivors slept very little. So their judgments  became impaired. For instance, one became convinced that Hitler was bombing London just to kill him personally.
The POV character in this story has a comrade-in-excavation who keeps finding survivors in a preternatural way. Little by little the former becomes convinced that the latter is a vampire, who follows the smell of the living people under the rubble.
But he is recruited in the army, and leaves London to fight abroad. He is hurt and sent in hospital in the UK. There another of his comrade-in-excavation (or maybe a son of one) visits him and tells him, among other news, that the "finder" has died digging survivors during an air raid.
IIRC, a blast had projected a piece of wood straight through his chest. Since this is the traditional only way to kill a vampire, the doubt of whether he actually was a vampire remains.
On the other hand, since the "finder" had come later than all the others to London, his hearing had not had time to be impaired by all the explosions the others have been submitted to. So he might have been able to hear sounds the others did not hear. In that case the story might have been completely "mundane". But it was clearly written in such a way that the reader thinks like the exhausted POV character and is convinced the other one is a vampire. And it was in a SF&F collection !

You're looking for Connie Willis' novella "Jack" (1991).
The narrator suspects Jack of being a vampire, because a couple of people they rescue end up dying shortly after, but there's no real evidence.
Jack's death:

"Didn't Dad tell you?" Quincy said with an anxious look at the transfusion bag hanging above the bed. "They had to dig past him to get to the little girl. It was pretty bad. Dad said. The blast from the D. A. had driven the leg of a chair straight through his chest."

It's been collected several times, but I have her collection Impossible Things which I recommend.  You can read the story, as it was originally published, in Asimov's at the Internet Archive.

Yes, indeed, there are no evidence. One can read the story as perfectly rational But the intent of the author is obviously to leave a doubt. Connie Willlis ! She has recycled all the research she did on the Blitz  for this story in her 2010 dyptich Blackout/All Clear LOL

@Alfred I would have rather said that she recycled all her research for Fire Watch (1982, and also a great read) instead...

Indeed ! I did read Fire Watch long ago but I forgot it predated the dyptich by so many years. And of course the dyptich left me  a stronger impression. But since Jack does not involve time-travel, I did not associate it to Connie WIllis "University of Oxford" series.

@Alfred do not forget "Not speaking of the dog", that took place during the Blitz as well.

@Edheldil Some of the "University of Oxford" stories are not during the Blitz at all,  I never claimed to give a full list of them. And though a part of "To say Nothing of the Dog" is during the Blitz, most of it in the Victorian era. But it is of course in that series. BTW, from what language did you "back-translate" the title of this book ?

@Alfred ah, the shame, mea culpa :). This will teach me to check the English name next time. I backtranslated the title from my internal Czech, as I read it years ago in English.

@Edheldil I learned EXACTLY ONE sentence in Czech (back in 1969) : Strč prst skrz krk. I even more or less remember what it means : put your finger into your throat. We are nor supposed to have long excahnges in comments. Do you know how to start a private discussion room ? So I can tell you the story..
